# call java script function On Change event of ActionSupport

Tags: visualforce, javascript, richtextarea

I am using CKEditor to rerender the rich text area.

Due to requirement,on change event of look up field, I need to get related information and display on Rich Text Area.

I am able to get info, but the ckeditor style is not applying to that paricular rich text area field.

I am referring to this [link](http://andrewbcummings.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/salesforce-richtext-fail-rerender-is-not-currently-supported-with-rich-text-editing-enabled/).

But for me, I am using on change event of Action Support because of my requirement.
However, it is not working properly and it can't display style class of ckeditor and only showing inputextfield.

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!getinfo}" reRender="myid" 
                oncomplete="ReloadCkEditor();"/>
```

It totally doesn't call ReloadCkEditor() function.

Comment: Can you check if you are able access the js file ckeditor.js using firebug. Check for any js errors in console. Is the controller method executing?

Comment: Write a javascript function ReloadCkEditor and in this function write an alert statement and see whether it is alerting or not. If it is alerting then check/debug the js files is loading or causing problems.